Does derived tensor product commute with fiber sequence in $\textbf{SCRing}$?
In lemma 3.1.5 of this paper I read, there is a fiber sequence of the underlying spaces of simplicial commutative rings $A\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} A\rightarrow A//f$. Here we define the "derived quotient' $A//f$ by the following homotopy pushout diagram: ($f$ is a point in $A$)

which we can also denote as $A\otimes^{L}_{Z[T] }Z[T]/(T)$.
I am wondering how we deduce the fiber sequence from the above definition. Here are my thoughts on this:
By the above definition, consider the exact sequence $Z[T]\stackrel{\cdot T}{\longrightarrow} Z[T]\rightarrow Z[T]/(T)$ ( which also is a fiber sequence), after the fully faithful embedding into the category of simplicial ring, which is a right adjoint to $\pi_{0}$ functor, is again a fiber sequence because right adjoint preserves pullbacks.
if the $\textbf{derived tensor product commutes with fiber sequence in SCRing}$, then from the above sequence we have $A\otimes_{Z[T]}^{L}Z[T]=A\stackrel{\cdot f}{\longrightarrow} A\otimes_{Z[T]}^{L}Z[T]=A\rightarrow A\otimes_{Z[T]}^{L}Z[T]/(T)=A//(f)$, which is a fiber sequence in $SCRing$, and geometric realization preserve pullbacks, thus we get the fiber sequences of the underlying spaces.
Here I just take the model category structure on $SCRing=Fun(\triangle^{op},CRing)$ and work with the (homotopy) (co)limits, I understand in many cases we are dealing with the infinity category structure on $SCRing$ as discussed in this post, probably using the infinity structure will be more convenient for the proof of this fiber sequence, any thoughts or comments on this question are very welcome.
